# $c_0(\mathcal{E})$ Notation Meaning, where $\mathcal{E}$ is an Orthonormal Basis

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-theory

A question from Conway's operator theory textbook, chapter 19 says

> Fix an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{E}$ for $\mathcal{H}$ and define $\eta :c_0(\mathcal{E}) \rightarrow \mathcal{B}_0$ by $\eta(\{\alpha _e\})=\sum \alpha _e e\otimes e$.

Here, $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space.

What is the meaning of $c_0(\mathcal{E})$? Since the notation is missing from the textbook's index of symbols, I searched it online. I guess it means the set of sequences with terms from $\mathcal{E}$ that converge to $0$. But since the elemetns of $\mathcal{E}$ have unit norm, how can that sequence converge to $0$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might by the set of “sequences” which are indexed by the elements of $\mathcal E$ (instead of natural numbers) and converging to zero.

Comment: @EikeSchulte Thanks. $\eta(\{\alpha _e\})=\sum \alpha _e e\otimes e$ checks out too.

Comment: $c_0(\mathcal{E})$ is defined for a set $\mathcal{E}$ of any cardinality as the functions $f:\mathcal{E}\to\Bbb{C}$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite subset $F\subseteq \mathcal{E}$ such that for all $x\in\mathcal{E}\setminus F$, $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.  It can be proved that any such $f$ is non-zero for only countably many points in $\mathcal{E}$.